# Recover existing object code in greenplum database

Tags: plpgsql, recovery, greenplum, flashback

One of my procedure in greenplum database is replaced by a wrong code.I want the old and correct version of the procedure. Is it possible in  greenplum database to recover the code?

Is there any function like Flashback in greenplum database?

Comment: Please do not tag Greenplum questions with Postgres: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/policy-on-postgresql-spin-offs

Comment: Greenplum is a postgresql database

Comment: It was ages ago, but it is no longer.

Comment: You can get the old code from your version control system (git, svn)

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum doesn't support many online transactional processing features such as flashback found in Oracle.